# Oracle 12c : Connecting through remote machine as SYSDBA user throws error ORA: 01017

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I have installed Oracle 12c with one pluggable database namely RHQDDBPDB.

I am successfully able to connect to my container database and pluggable database as sysdba through SQL developer on my DB server

I have created one user rhqddbpdbadmin on my pluggable database RHQDDBPDB with sysdba role. I am able to connect to pluggable database with this user as sysdba.

The problem that I am facing is as follows:

When connecting to the Container or Pluggable database through SQLPLUS from another machine as sysdba, I am getting error ORA-01017.

However from remote machine, if I connect with rhqddbpdbadmin user as Normal (without sysdba), then connection is successfull.

Commands i am using from remote machine:

sqlplus rhqddbpdbadmin/xxxxxx@rhqddbpdb as sysdba

Throws error ORA - 01017

sqlplus rhqddbpdbadmin/xxxxxx@rhqddbpdb

Connected successfully.

Please help.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry for a silly question, but did you google 'sysdba ora-01017'?  The first   [search result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116445/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-while-connecting-to-an-instance-remotely) cites many possible reasons for the error.

Comment: Can you please let us know which version of 12c are you using?

Comment: Oracle version is 12.2.0.1.0. Also I have Googled thoroughly, but unable to find a reason.

Comment: I would also like to clarify that the all the remote machines from where I am trying to connect as sysdba have Oracle 11g client or database installed.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting as sysdba from a remote location (over tcp or tcps) requires some extra steps:

1. Set the database parameter `REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE = { shared | exclusive | none }`.It should be set tp shared/exclusive.
2. Check your password file under $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/, which is being used for authentication when users login to the database as a sysdba. If the password file does not exist then create a new one (using orapwd) and set the password.

Comment: I needed a password file to allow remote users to log in as sys to do app/db patching on a new development database